Unity Vuforia create image target in runtime
I am using Unity 2022.3.15f and Vuforia 10.22.5
I am trying to create image targets by API in runtime and attach quad with video to each image targets
It works well in unity but when i build android version my video player works very bad
where can be misstake? i have simular app in unity 2019.4.0f but there i create targets by database downloaded from target manager in vuforia
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.Video;
using Vuforia;

public class GetJson : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string url = "https://api.arstudio.kz/api/ar?groupId=82";
    [SerializeField] private RootObject loadinfolist = new RootObject();
    public GameObject Model;
    public UnityEngine.UI.Image LoadingLogo;

    private string path;
    private float loadProgress = 0.0f;

    private void Start()
    {
        path = Application.persistentDataPath; // Установка пути один раз
        VuforiaApplication.Instance.OnVuforiaInitialized += OnVuforiaInitialized;
    }

    void OnVuforiaInitialized(VuforiaInitError error)
    {
        StartCoroutine(SendReq());
    }

    private IEnumerator SendReq()
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
        {
            yield return request.SendWebRequest();

            if (request.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                Debug.Log(request.error);
            }
            else
            {
                loadinfolist = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject>(request.downloadHandler.text);
                StartCoroutine(WebAR());
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator WebAR()
    {
        foreach (Datum data in loadinfolist.data)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(DownloadAndSetupContent(data));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator DownloadAndSetupContent(Datum data)
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(DownloadVideo(data.video_path, data.id, data.group_id));
        yield return StartCoroutine(DownloadImageAndCreateTarget(data.file_path, data.id, data.group_id));
    }

    private IEnumerator DownloadVideo(string videoPath, int id, int groupId)
    {
        string savePath = $"{path}/{id}_{groupId}.mp4";
        using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(videoPath))
        {
            yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
            if (uwr.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, uwr.downloadHandler.data);
                loadProgress += 1.0f / loadinfolist.data.Length;
                LoadingLogo.fillAmount = loadProgress;
                Debug.Log("Video downloaded to: " + savePath);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(uwr.error);
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator DownloadImageAndCreateTarget(string imagePath, int id, int groupId)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(imagePath))
        {
            yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
            if (uwr.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                Texture2D texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);
                CreateImageTargetFromDownloadedTexture(id, $"{path}/{id}_{groupId}.mp4", texture);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(uwr.error);
            }
        }
    }

    void CreateImageTargetFromDownloadedTexture(int id, string videoUrl, Texture2D img)
    {
        var mTarget = VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.ObserverFactory.CreateImageTarget(img, 1.0f, id.ToString());
        mTarget.gameObject.AddComponent<DefaultObserverEventHandler>();
        GameObject cube = Instantiate(Model, mTarget.transform);
        cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(mTarget.GetSize().x, mTarget.GetSize().y, 1.0f);

        VideoPlayer player = cube.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        player.url = videoUrl;
        EventHandler eventHandler = mTarget.gameObject.AddComponent<EventHandler>();
        Debug.Log("Target with video player created for: " + id);
    }
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Group
{

    [SerializeField] public int id;
    [SerializeField] public string name;
    [SerializeField] public string created_at;
    [SerializeField] public string updated_at;
    [SerializeField] public int user_id;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Datum
{
    [SerializeField] public int id ;
    [SerializeField] public int group_id ;
    [SerializeField] public int user_id ;
    [SerializeField] public string file_path ;
    [SerializeField] public string video_path ;
    [SerializeField] public string mind_file_path ;
    [SerializeField] public string status ;
    [SerializeField] public int is_deleted ;
    [SerializeField] public string created_at ;
    [SerializeField] public string updated_at ;
    [SerializeField] public int width ;
    [SerializeField] public int height ;
}


Could you elaborate on what "my video player works really bad" means? Is it slow, blurry, jerky or what other symptoms are there?

it is like slowly and jerkly,there is a delay during the transition from one frame to another
